# Excel Formula Tally sheet

Tags: excel-formula

i was using a formula to tally the total of 28, when the user type done on remarks, it will increment finished and subtract value from remaining but i can't get it work, heres a link to the image preview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hJto.jpg

```
=IF(D9:D36="done",B4+1,IF(B$4=1,B$3-1))
```

please help

Comment: In which cell(s) are you putting this formula?

Comment: on the remaining and the finished cells, you can see it if you click the image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `if` statement and getting into CSE formulas and circular reference issues, which is where your formula is heading, use a `COUNTIF` function.

In your "Remaining" cell use the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D36, "<>" & "done")
```

*This will calculate the number of cells in the D3:D36 range that are not equal "<>" to the word "done"*

In your "Finished" cell use the foromula:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D36, "done")
```